# Run MongoDB in Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, nosql

How to run MongoDB on WindowsAzure? Should instance be deployed on a virtual machine? Are there any out-of-the-box solutions like images for virtual machines or anything else? How to run replica sets on WindowsAzure?

I saw this article http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/windows-azure/ but I feel like it is already out of date. Is it?

Any best practices, help or info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The article that you refer to describes the options quite well. You have three options:

1. Running MongoDB in worker roles (as linked to in the article). Before Azure VMs, worker roles were the only option, but I wouldn't recommend it.
2. You can try the MongoDB database as as service offerings that are available in the add-ons store. This would be a good way to try it out. For longer term, you will have to ask around for peoples' experience.
3. I recommend that you run MongoDB on a Linux VM. That way you have full control and support from the linux/MongoDB community. Replica sets would the be 'out the box'. The article links to a walkthrough on a CentOS image. You can also get a pre-built image from VMDepot such as [this Ubuntu one](http://vmdepot.msopentech.com/Vhd/Show?vhdId=149&version=154). The VMDepot images seem to work very well and are a good start for people with less Linux experience.

**Edit**: MongoLab seems to be [gaining traction, and is getting support from Scott Guthrie](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/22/announcing-new-mongodb-instances-on-microsoft-azure.aspx). As a service that has affinity with Azure datacentres, it is worth evaluating.

Comment: I used MongoLab in the past and now run my own MongoDB cluster using IaaS Linux VMs. Self plug, I use this: www.jeff.wilcox.name/2013/09/mongodb-azure-linux/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/welcome/) - [Here goes the Tutorial on Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-mongolab-web-sites-dotnet-store-data-mongodb/)

Using MongoLab all the maintenance (atleast in DB engine itself) will be taken care by MongoLab guys. That will remove lot of maintenance overheads on your side.